# serializeArray() does not pick up form fields that have been added after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

serializeArray() does not pick up form fields that have been added after page load (by #jQuery). Why? How can I resolv?

Edit: See code below. I'm quite new to javascript/jquery and therefore I guess I'm missing something quite obvious (haven't been able to find it on google though).

The new row has been added by running addFormRow (as OnClick in HTML). The new row is added to the page but not used when I run submitFormJSON (or $('form :input') in console).

```
function addFormRow(){
    var newrow = document.createElement('article');
    newrow.innerHTML = 'Name: <input type="text" name="rowName" value="" /> Description: <input type="text" name="rowDescription" value="" /> Type: <select name="rowType"><option value="text">Text</option><option value="textarea">Textarea</option><option value="email">Email</option><option value="checkbox">Checkbox</option><option value="radio">Radio button</option><option value="date">Date</option><option value="range">Range</option><option value="url">URL</option><option value="number">Number</option><option value="time">Time</option><option value="dropdown">Drop Down</option></select>';
    document.getElementById("section").appendChild(newrow);
}

function submitFormJSON(strURL, strType) {
        var objFormValues = {};
        $.each($('form').serializeArray(), function(key,value) {
            objFormValues[value.name] = value.value;
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: strType,
            url: strURL,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: objFormValues,
            success: function(msg) {
                alert( "Data Saved!");
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: are the dynamically added form fields have the `name` attribute?

Comment: Yes, the new fields have a name attribute. The new fields are in a article tag though. Could that be the problem?

Comment: and this section element is inside your form ?

Comment: Well the element is but now I realize that I'm using getElementById and the id "section" is not.. That seems to solve the problem. Sorry for taking your time because of such a mistake..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the fields you added on page load in the same form element which you are trying to searialize.

Comment: Is section container within in the form tag?

Comment: as I wrote to 3nigma: "Well the element is but now I realize that I'm using getElementById and the id "section" is not.. That seems to solve the problem. Sorry for taking your time because of such a mistake"

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to serialize an array immediately on page load, have you tried the trigger function from the jQuery library.  Or use raw js and do

```
window.onload = function() {
  doSomething();
};
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onload

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: That is quite the opposite of what I want.. =) My problem is that only input fields that are on the page during page load is used. I would like to include input fields that have been added after page load..

Comment: if the new input fields are being created dynamically then you should assign the event handler to a variable and return those values either in an array ie var myVar = function() { generate inputs; return []; ); then serialize myVar

Comment: some actual code would be helpful also, don't want to keep guessing the solution, throw something up on www.jsfiddle.com